# C# Blazor Server-Side CSS Element Leak Using InvokeVoidAsync

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

Trying to hack a transition experience when removing a row from a column. Something like Vue/React. Calling InvokeVoidAsync to append a class that will perform an animation. The javascript call also has a sleep call that will postpone the actual item from being removed on the server side. After the server removes the item, the class is applied to the item below it. [Example of a table row appending the class to the next table row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFVZu.gif) [UI Side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u7b9.gif)

I created a Blazor Server Side Application and updated the Index.razor page, added a couple js functions, and a css file.

**Index.razor**

```
@page "/"

<h2> @Pizzas.Count() Pizza's</h2>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var pizza in Pizzas)
        {
            <tr id="@(pizza.ID)">
                <td>@pizza.Name</td>
                <td><button @onclick="@(async _ => await RemovePizza(pizza))">Remove</button></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@code {
    public record Pizza(Guid ID, string Name);
    public string[] PizzaTypes => new[] { "Pepperoni", "Cheese", "Hawaiian", "Veggie", "Bacon", "Southwestern BBQ", "Cheeseburger", "Buffalo", "Meat", "Supreme" };

    public List<Pizza> Pizzas { get; set; } = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                AddPizza();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void AddPizza()
    {
        Pizzas.Add(new Pizza(Guid.NewGuid(), PizzaTypes[new Random().Next(0, PizzaTypes.Length - 1)]));
    }
    public async Task RemovePizza(Pizza pizza)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("animateTransition", pizza.ID, "fade-away", 1000);
        Pizzas.Remove(pizza);
    }
}
```

**JS Functions**

```
var sleep = async (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

var animateTransition = async (id, className, duration) => {
    const el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.classList.add(className);
    await sleep(duration);
};
```

**CSS**

```
@keyframes fadeOut {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

tr.fade-away {
    animation-name: fadeOut;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My apologies. My question is: Am I doing something wrong to remove a table row that is causing the class to apply to the table row below or is it an issue with blazor?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing the @key attribution within the loop. Such a novice mistake.

https://blazor-university.com/components/render-trees/optimising-using-key/

**Updated Code**

```
@foreach (var pizza in Pizzas)
    {
        <tr @key="pizza" id="@(pizza.ID)">
            <td>@pizza.Name</td>
            <td><button @onclick="@(async _ => await RemovePizza(pizza))">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
    }
```